# maximizing number of lattice points with bounded diameter

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, lattices

Suppose I have a lattice $L$ that's just $\mathbb{Z}^k$ but scaled in every coordinate by some (potentially different) real numbers. Now I want to construct a finite set of lattice points $S \subset L$ such that I know $S$'s $L_1$-diameter (max of pairwise $L_1$ distances) is bounded above by some $d$. **I want to maximize $|S|$.**

I looked around and couldn't find an answer. Naively, it seems like the following argument should work:

1. This should be "almost like" maximizing the volume of a convex (if there are "holes" you can move extremal points into the holes without increasing the diameter) body $B$ (in our case it seems we can assume a polytope, but not necessarily a lattice polytope) with diameter $d$.
2. The $B$ that solves this constraint "should" be the $L_1$-ball, which should have volume $d^k/k!$.
3. $B$ should have "about" $\frac{d^k}{k! \operatorname{vol}(L_0)}$ lattice points, where $\operatorname{vol}(L_0)$ is the volume of the fundamental parallelopiped of $L$.

I'm having trouble making these arguments rigorously and I'm a bit wary of reinventing the wheel, so... **does this approach "morally" work?** If so, are there good references? Most of the sources I've seen *start* with the convex body and then compute things like $L \cap B$, but here it's a bit awkward as I'm moving from the diameter on the lattice points to the convex body and I need to justify the optimization problem translates correctly.

One particular complaint about the problem (or just my incompetence!) is that it does not seem obvious that I can reduce to the case $\mathbb{Z}^k$, because it is not that obvious that the $L_1$-constraints of the "squished" $\mathbb{Z}^k$ plays well with the approximation to a polytope. But even this would be a useful step (then it starts looking closer to e.g. the Gauss circle problem).

Comment: You want to maximize $|S|$ given some diameter constraint $d$.
It seems equivalent to maximize $\frac{|S|}{d^n}$, where $d^n$ is introduced to make the quantity scale-invariant (sort of --- here I am being imprecise and identifying $|S|$ with volume of the convex hull of $S$). Equivalently, you can minimize $\frac{d^n}{|S|}$. At least in $\ell_2$, this is often called the "thickness of the lattice covering", and there is quite a bit written about it, say for example in Conway and Sloane's *Sphere Packings, Lattices, and Groups*. This isn't an answer as your setting both has $|S|$ as a point

Comment: count, rather than a volume, and is $\ell_1$, and not $\ell_2$, but hopefully this is still somewhat useful.

Comment: Yeah I feel the hard part is making the "point count to volume" rigorous here, but this is a novel direction for me to search / learn as well, so thanks!

Comment: it isn't rigorous in that it leads to an equality, but you can get bounds. For example, it is straightforward to see that $|S\cap\mathbb{Z}^n| \leq \mathsf{vol}(S + \mathcal{B}_\infty^n(1/2))$, where $+$ is the Minkowski sum, and $B_\infty^n(1/2) = [-1/2,1/2]^n$ is the $\ell_\infty$ ball of radius $1/2$. Then, if you care about $\ell_1$ diameter, you can write something like $S\subseteq B_1^n(\mathsf{diam}(S)/2)$ and $B_\infty^n(1/2) \subseteq B_1^n(n/2)$ to get an upper bound on the point count in terms of solely $\ell_1$ quantities. I remember there being a similar argument for the lower

Comment: bound, but don't recall it offhand.

Comment: it's worth mentioning there are more refined arguments available, at least in the setting of $\ell_2$. For a lattice $L$ one can often get estimates for $|L\cap (B_2^n(r) +t)|$ in terms of the *gaussian mass* of the lattice. See the introduction of [noah stephens-davidowitz's thesis](https://cs.nyu.edu/media/publications/stephens-davidowitz_noah.pdf) for some exposition on this. I don't know if the gaussian arguments extend past $\ell_2$ though.